# Infinite graphs satisfying a certain Ramsey property

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $G$ be a countably infinite graph. If $G$ has cliques of arbitrarily large finite size, then $G$ satisfies the following property, which I will call $(*)$: for any $r\in \mathbb{N}$ and any $r$-coloring of the edges of $G$, some triangle must be monochromatic. This is a simple consequence of Ramsey's theorem.

My question is whether the converse is true; namely, if $G$ is a countably infinite graph with property $(*)$, then must $G$ have arbitrarily large cliques?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For graphs $G,H$ and for $r\in\mathbb N$ let $G\to(H)_r^2$ denote the statement: any $r$-coloring of the edges of $G$ contains a monochromatic subgraph isomorphic to $H$.

Your question is answered in the negative by the Nešetřil-Rödl theorem: for any $r,m\in\mathbb N$ and any $K_m$-free finite graph $H$, there is a $K_m$-free finite graph $G$ such that $G\to(H)_r^2$. In particular, for any $r\in\mathbb N$, there is a $K_4$-free finite graph $G_r$ such that $G_r\to(K_3)_r^2$. The disjoint union of the graphs $G_r$ is a $K_4$-free countable graph $G$ such that $G\to(K_3)_r^2$ for every $r\in\mathbb N$.

**Reference:** J. Nešetřil and V. Rödl, The Ramsey property for graphs with forbidden complete subgraphs, J. Combinatorial Theory Ser. B 20 (1976), 243-249.

Comment: Very cool! Any chance the analogous result is also true for hypergraphs?

Comment: @Andy Good question! Unfortunately I'm no expert (on anything, which includes Ramsey theory) and it was sheer luck that I happened to know the answer to your first question. If my life depended on finding the answer to your generalized question, here are the strategies I might try: (1) look in books with "Ramsey theory" in the title; (2) do a literature search using "Nešetřil", "Rödl", and "Ramsey theory" as keywords; (3) learn the proof(s) of the Nešetřil-Rödl theorem and think about how to generalize it; (4) ask Nešetřil or Rödl; (5) hope one of those guys is on MSE and finds this query.

Comment: @Andy You can probably find the answer to your new question in the book [*Mathematics of Ramsey Theory*](http://www.springer.com/new+%26+forthcoming+titles+(default)/book/978-3-642-72907-2) edited by Nešetřil and Rödl.